# Запуск Skype с сайта

Tags: javascript, skype

Как сделать так, чтобы пользователь нажимал кнопку на сайте и у него открывался скайп?
У меня пока 2 идеи, это javascript'ом через ActiveX, но работать будет только в IE и ссылкой типа `file://c:\program files\skype`... но если скайп установлен в другой директории. Может, кто чего подскажет?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Разбирайтесь в протоколе skype - есть команды на запуск и т.п.
Например: ссылка типа `skype:echo123?call` - запрос на вызов, а `skype:echo123?status` - соответственно на просмотр состояния.

Comment: не подскажете где прочитать про такое?в документации не встречал такого(.в поиске нашел

"Echo123 - это встроенный сервис для тестирования качества звука. Он помогает проверить, правильно ли подключены и настроены колонки, микрофон или гарнитура.
Введите "echo123" в адресной строке в нижней части Skype или добавьте этот сервис в свой Контакт-лист. Вызов Echo123 запустит автоматическое тестирование и позволит вам убедиться в правильной настройке звука."

Comment: `<a href="skype:echo123?call">echo123</a>`

Comment: @thedarkelf, echo123 - это пример, можно любой логин вписать туда

Answer (score 1):

У скайпа есть плагин `click-to-call`, но он используется как надостройка в броузере (при установке скайпа это гадость включается, а потом отключается пользователем), иначе никак.